# Laravel 5.3 auth methods implementation / overwriting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Which classes, and which methods are responsible in Laravel 5.3 for default user login / logout / register and password reset functions? And where can i find it? I want to modificate such things like default redirectPath, flash messages after success e.t.c

Comment: Could you please let us know if our answers solved you problem or if you need more help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these are the correct controllers and methods you are looking for. Keep in mind that most or all of the methods are not found directly in the respective controllers, but inside traits that these controllers use. But they are easy to locate either by opening up the controller and stepping into the trait that it uses, or by just searching for the name of the method in PHPStorm or any other IDE or editor.

```html
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register
```

#### Example

Let's say you want to locate the *[showLoginForm()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L18)* method.

- Open up {root}/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
- Notice that it uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`
- Open up `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`
- The first method you see should be *[showLoginForm()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L18)*

```php
 /**
 * Show the application's login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Comment: Both answers are correct but i choose this one, because it is more detailed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.3 there are few controllers in `app\Http\Controllers\Auth`:

```
LoginController
RegisterController
ResetPasswordController
ChangePasswordController
ForgotPasswordController
```

You can safely override default auth methods in these controllers. What exactly method you want to override depends on your needs. For example, if you need to redirect users depending on their role, you need to override [`sendLoginResponse()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L86) method by creating and modifying it in `LoginController`.